# Flutter audioplayers no sound at all on android but works on web

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, audio, plugins

Can someone help me please with audioplayers on Flutter? I'm creating a radio player on Flutter. The sound should play from the URL. Assets and all set up correctly. I can't get sound at all on android but it works on the web browser. Flutter doesn't throw any errors. So can't figure out what's going wrong and where.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:internet_radio_app/model/radio.dart';
import 'package:internet_radio_app/utils/ai_util.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<MyRadio> radios;
  MyRadio _selectedRadio;
  Color _selectedColor;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  final AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchRadios();

    _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
      if (event == PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        _isPlaying = true;
      } else {
        _isPlaying = false;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  fetchRadios() async {
    final radioJson = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/radio.json");
    radios = MyRadioList.fromJson(radioJson).radios;
    print(radios);
    setState(() {});
  }

  _playMusic(String url) {
    _audioPlayer.play(url);
    _selectedRadio = radios.firstWhere((element) => element.url == url);
    print(_selectedRadio.name);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          VxAnimatedBox()
              .size(context.screenWidth, context.screenHeight)
              .withGradient(
                LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    AIColors.primaryColor2,
                    _selectedColor ?? AIColors.primaryColor1,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                ),
              )
              .make(),
          AppBar(
            title: "AI Radio".text.xl4.bold.white.make().shimmer(
                  primaryColor: Vx.purple300,
                  secondaryColor: Colors.white,
                ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
          ).h(100.0).p16(),
          radios != null
              ? VxSwiper.builder(
                  itemCount: radios.length,
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  onPageChanged: (index) {
                    final colorHex = radios[index].color;
                    _selectedColor = Color(int.tryParse(colorHex));
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final rad = radios[index];

                    return VxBox(
                            child: ZStack(
                      [
                        Positioned(
                          top: 0.0,
                          right: 0.0,
                          child: VxBox(
                            child:
                                rad.category.text.uppercase.white.make().px16(),
                          )
                              .height(40)
                              .black
                              .alignCenter
                              .withRounded(value: 10.0)
                              .make(),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: VStack(
                            [
                              rad.name.text.xl3.white.bold.make(),
                              5.heightBox,
                              rad.tagline.text.sm.white.semiBold.make(),
                            ],
                            crossAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: [
                              Icon(
                                CupertinoIcons.play_circle,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              10.heightBox,
                              "Double tap to play".text.gray300.make(),
                            ].vStack()),
                      ],
                    ))
                        .clip(Clip.antiAlias)
                        .bgImage(
                          DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(rad.image),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  BlendMode.darken)),
                        )
                        .border(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 5.0,
                        )
                        .withRounded(value: 60.0)
                        .make()
                        .onInkDoubleTap(() {
                      _playMusic(rad.url);
                    }).p16();
                  },
                ).centered()
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: [
              if (_isPlaying)
                "Playing Now -${_selectedRadio.name} FM"
                    .text
                    .white
                    .makeCentered(),
              Icon(
                _isPlaying
                    ? CupertinoIcons.stop_circle
                    : CupertinoIcons.play_circle,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 50.0,
              ).onInkTap(() {
                if (_isPlaying) {
                  _audioPlayer.stop();
                } else {
                  _playMusic(_selectedRadio.url);
                }
              }),
            ].vStack(),
          ).pOnly(bottom: context.percentHeight * 12),
        ],
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do your URLs have SSL certificate or not? I mean https?

Comment: having a similar issue. Any fixes?

Comment: Same issue with me any solution?

Answer (score 1):

adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" within your AndroidManifest.xml file located in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```